# Проверка формы на заполненность

Tags: php, ajax, форма

У меня есть ajax форма по ссылке https://www.archiv.ru/about/career/
Данная форма реализована через ajax обращение к отправщику php

Когда проверяю вручную отправку, то он не дает отправить письмо, пока e-mail не заполнен
Но на почту время от времени получаю письма с пустой формой
Хотел бы узнать, как отправляются пустые письма мне, если я сам не могу пустое письмо отправить?

Comment: проверять надо в РНР, а не только в JS

Comment: а как у вас обработчик работает? Роботы могут заходить на страницу `/ajax/send-career.php`, тем самым отправляя пустые письма

Comment: Самое правильное решение, проверять еще и в php верно?

Answer (score 0):

Однозначно нужно проверять данные и на стороне клиента, и на стороне сервера. На стороне клиента - для самого юзера, чтобы он видел, что он не заполнил. На стороне сервера - для функционала. Php в данном случае не должен знать, есть валидация на какой то форме или нет, к примеру у вас будет 2 формы но один обработчик, в одной форме есть валидация в другой нету, как быть? Так же в вашем случае, лучше поменять тип запроса с GET на POST, и в обработчике реализовать еще одну проверку на метод запроса. Делать валидацию данных нужно в любом случае, и при реализации обработчика вы не должны думать о форме или откуда к вам данные приходят.